# How to make udemy timer with mysql and laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, timer

I want to have todo list with hour timer for finishing the task. As an example: Learn how to subtract hours from database column | 48h. When I chunked end_hour column I can use Carbon but I can't merge chunked table with rest of the table. How to make proper countdown timer with mysql and laravel - similar to Udemy.com

Comment: Say what? Can you explain in terms of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible option is you could save the "start" time to the database, and then on the front end use Javascript to subtract 1 hour from the time difference between the "start" time and the current time.  You can provide your "start" time to the front end by outputting it when you make your view from your controller.

So in your view, you'd have something like this:

```
<script>
setInterval(function() {
    var d = new Date();
    var current_timestamp = d.getTime(); 
    var one_hour_in_milliseconds = 60 * 60 * 1000;
    var time_left = one_hour_in_milliseconds - ({{$start_time}} - current_timestamp);
    console.log(time_left);   
}, 1000);

</script>
```

and that way, every second you should see an updated time in the console (which you could display anywhere you want) that gives you how much time is left.

Comment: Thanks. That is what I'm looking for.